# Devise: Redirect to the restricted page the user was originally trying to access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've seen many questions about redirecting the user to the last page he was on using devise.  There's a good explanation and sample code [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update)

That works for me and it's what I want sometimes but other times, I want the redirection to be to the restricted page the user was trying to access NOT the page he was previously on.  For example:

1. User hits "create new post button" which is on the home page
2. This hits the posts controller, new action which is protected with a before_filter that requires the user to login
3. The user is redirected to the login page
4. After logging in, the user is now redirected to the home page.
5. BUT, in this situation, I wanted the user to be redirected to the new action with the new post form which he was trying to access, not the home page.

Comment: The sample code on GitHub does exactly what you describe!?

Comment: I've tested it.  It redirects to the last page the user was on, not the one he's trying to get to.  I.e. in my example, the sample code would redirect the user to the home page and not the new post page.

Comment: So you should set this session variable only when the user tried to access a restricted page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I realized that in order to redirect to the protected page the user was trying to access after signing in, the store_location function needs to be a before_filter not an after_filter.

```
before_filter :store_location

def store_location
  # store last url as long as it isn't a /users path
  session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath unless request.fullpath =~ /\/users/
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  session[:previous_url] || root_path
end
```

This makes sense because the session variable gets set in this case to the protected page because the store_location function is executed right when I try to access the `new_post_path` for example.  When you have store_location as an after_filter like in github code sample, then the last time the store_location function was executed was when I was when a non protected action was reached i.e. the home page in my example.

Comment: Thanks so much! I had exactly the same issue after using the suggested code you referenced. Found any cases where making it a before_filter causes any problems? Seems so obvious now you've explained it, why isn't this in the example they gave?

Answer (score 0):

Set the current path before you redirect to the login page with the following snippet:

```
session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath unless request.fullpath =~ /\/users/
```

Check this session variable after a successful log in, if it's setted and then redirect to it.